# Android accessibility - is there a way to detect if talk back is reading content description

Tags: android, mobile, accessibility

I've got a ListView that's gets populated with data from the server (phone numbers) and I'm polling every 2 seconds. When TalkBack feature is switched on and the I tap on a list item, the talkBack doesn't get the chance to read the whole string because the refresh occurs and the talkBack starts from the begging. Is there a way to detect if the TalkBack if content description is being read? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried enabling stable IDs in your list adapter?

Comment: Hi Alanv. I just tried your solution and it works. Thank you very much! Please post your solution as an answer and I shall accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` relies on the value of [`Adapter.hasStableIds()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#hasStableIds()) to determine if inflated views can be reused across data set changes.

If this method returns `false`, ListView assumes that there is no consistency between the data set before and after a change. As a result, it doesn't know where accessibility focus should be placed.

However, if this method returns `true` and your adapter maintains a consistent mapping between item ID and data, then ListView is able to maintain accessibility focus on the correct item -- even if it changes position within the data set.

To fix this issue, you can modify your adapter to maintain stable IDs:

```
class MyAdapter extends ListAdapter {
    ...

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // Return a consistent mapping between the item at a given
        // position and an arbitrary (but consistent!) ID associated
        // with that item.
        ...
    }
}
```